# Content Security Policy invalid characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, content-security-policy

Chrome is returning this error on the console while defining basic csp codes:

> The Content-Security-Policy directive name 'Content-Security-Policy:'
> contains one or more invalid characters. Only ASCII alphanumeric
> characters or dashes '-' are allowed in directive names.

This is all I have on my .htaccess file:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

Is there anything wrong you can see? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have an error. You forgot a ";" before script-src:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there is one more issue:
The colon `:` after `script-src`

This is how it should be:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```